# How to display calendar events on lockscreen in Oreo?

Tags: lock-screens, calendar, nexus-5x, 8.0-oreo

There are similar questions for previous Android releases.

Is it possible in Android 8 Oreo on a stock Nexus 5X to customise the lock screen to display upcoming calendar events? Google Pixel 2(XL) allows this.

(the image is of a home screen, but the question is specifically for the lock screen)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Calendar notify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cliffcawley.calendarnotify) does a great job showing the agenda using persistent notifications.

If you'd like a more stock look, and if you are willing to root your phone and install the xposed framework (after it is released for oreo), then [EventLock](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.gobbledygook.theawless.eventlock) (disclosure: it's written by me) is what you are looking for.